# How to animate a vector field along a given curve?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

Happy 2022!

I want to animate a vector field along a given curve, using `gganimate` and `ggplot`, so that at any given moment the current frame shows only the vector at the current position along the curve, but the entire curve is shown in every frame. I would really appreciate any help?

In the code chunk below, I almost created what I want but the curve loops back. Also, the curve looks very pixelated. There must be a way to turn this geom_function into a layer so that the entire curve is displayed in every frame, without looping back.

**My code:**

```
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)
data<- tibble(x = seq(0,20,by = 0.1), y = sqrt(x) , vx = 1, vy = 1)
p<-ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_function(fun=function(u) sqrt(u), xlim=c(0,20), col="gray") +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x + vx, yend = y + vy), 
               arrow = arrow(angle = 30, length = unit(2, "mm"),
               ends = "last", type = "open"), col="blue")
p + transition_reveal(x)
```

**An output:**

[image]